# how to fix: "out of line definition of 'graph' does not match any declaration in 'graph'"

Tags: c++, xcode, class, declaration

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef int vertex;

enum vertexstate { white, gray, black };

class graph
{
private: 
        bool**adjacencymatrix;
        int vertexcount;
public: 
        graph(int vertexcount);
        ~graph();

        void addedge(int i, int j);
        void removeedge(int i, int j);
        bool isedge(int i, int j);

        void display();
        void Dfs();
        void runDfs(int u, vertexstate state[]);
};

graph::graph(char filename[], int vertexcount)  //error is here
{
    this->vertexcount = vertexcount;
    adjacencymatrix = new bool*[vertexcount];

    for (int i = 0; i<vertexcount; i++)
    {
        adjacencymatrix[i] = new bool[vertexcount];
        for (int j = 0; j<vertexcount; j++)
            adjacencymatrix[i][j] = false;
    }
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear; `graph` contains no declaration of that constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from your code sample being incomplete and you not really formulating a question....

Your constructor is defined as `graph(int vertexcount);` yet your implementation uses different parameters: `graph(char filename[], int vertexcount)`.

You have 2 possibilities depending on what you are tryin to achieve:

1) You can change the definition in your class to `graph(char filename[], int vertexcount)`

2) You can change your implementation to read like this:#

```
graph::graph(int vertexcount)
{
    this->vertexcount = vertexcount;
    adjacencymatrix = new bool*[vertexcount];

    for (int i = 0; i<vertexcount; i++)
    {
        adjacencymatrix[i] = new bool[vertexcount];
        for (int j = 0; j<vertexcount; j++)
            adjacencymatrix[i][j] = false;
    }
}
```

---

In case you need filename: I would recommend to use `const std::string&` as parameter type - or at least `const char*`...